# Alamofire 5 custom SSL validation against multiple CA

Tags: swift, validation, ssl, alamofire

With Alamofire 4 I was able to validate that my server certificate was valid against local CA or my own CA implementing `taskDidReceiveChallengeWithCompletion`.
With Alamofire 5 this method is not available anymore.
I need to fundamentally have that a single host can validate against pinned certificate, and in case it's not valid validation will be performed with normal ssl validation.
The ServerTrustManager has `ServerTrustPolicy` which is a dictionary, so it is possible to have only 1 type of validation per host.
Anyone got the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Create your own `ServerTrustEvaluating` value and use it for your domain. Functionally, you would copy your previous implementation into a type which implements the protocol

```swift
struct MyEvaluator: ServerTrustEvaluating {
  func evaluate(_ trust: SecTrust, forHost host: String) throws {
    // Custom logic.
  }
}
```

You can read more in the [documentation](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/AdvancedUsage.md#security).